# replace multi line text with multiline text in sed and perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

Here is my file

```
      start
      exit 0

      status
      exit 0

      stop
      exit 0
```

the result file should be

```
      start
      exit 0

      status
      exit 152

      stop
      exit 0
```

any help is appreciated
How can I do it using sed and perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Awk`

**Input**

```
$ cat f
      start
      exit 0

      status
      exit 0

      stop
      exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/exit/ && p {sub($NF,"152")}{p=/status/}1'  f
      start
      exit 0

      status
      exit 152

      stop
      exit 0
```

**Explanation**

- `p=/status/` Set variable `p` true whenever `awk` finds word status
- `/exit/ && p`   when `awk` finds word **exit** on current record and variable `p` evaluates true then

> sub(regexp, replacement [, target])

Search target, which is treated as a string, for the leftmost, longest substring matched by the regular expression regexp. Modify the entire string by replacing the matched text with replacement. The modified string becomes the new value of target. Return the number of substitutions made (zero or one).  If 3rd argument is omitted, then the default is to use and alter `$0`.

- `sub($NF,"152")`

Substitute last field (`$NF`) with `152` of current record, since 3rd argument is not given hence, default `$0` is altered.

- `} 1`

`1` always evaluates to true, it performs default operation `{print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe's/exit \K\d+/152/ if $f; $f = /status/'
```

Usage:

```
perl -i~ -pe'...' file            # Edit in place with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file             # Edit in place without backup
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out   # Read from file
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out  # Read from stdin
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what about using sed

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Using sed for anything else is completely inappropriate as there's always more clear, efficient, robust, portable, maintainable, extensible, etc. ways to do whatever it is you want to do and it would require use of arcane language constructs that became obsolete over 40 years ago when awk was invented.

Answer (score 0):

With sed one can use:

```
$ sed '/status/{n;s/0/152/}' input
      start
      exit 0

      status
      exit 152

      stop
      exit 0
```